# Node.JS async showing "Promise" in returned data

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have the following node.js function call and function

```
var returned = checkCurrentProcesses()
    returned.then(() => {
        console.log(returned)

    })

function checkCurrentProcesses() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        exec('pgrep -u user123 -x node  -a', (err, cmdOutput, stderr) => {
            if (err) {
                reject({error:err})
            }
            else{
                resolve({output:cmdOutput})
            }
        });
    })

}
```

This successfully reruns the data I need, however it returns it in a way that I'm not understanding. I'm expecting to get a return of the resolved condition which is an object. But when I console.log(returned) the output looks as follows, and the data is an object in an object, and I'm unable to access it.

```
Promise { { output: '26278 node nodeMasterServer.js list\n' } }
```

Even if I simplify the code, the return is the same format.

```
function checkCurrentProcesses() {
    return new Promise(resolve =>{
        resolve({thisIs:"aTest"})
    })
}

Promise { { thisIs: 'aTest' } }
```

What is causing this behavior, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, you need to pass the data to the `then` callback as so:

```
var returned = checkCurrentProcesses()
    returned.then((data) => { // can be any name you want
        console.log(data) // the object you are expecting

    })
```

Comment: Thank you!  output now shows correctly as `{ thisIs: 'aTest' }`